# WSO2 API Manager: Can Consumer Key & Consumer Secret be changed?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In WSO2 API Manager, is it possible to change the auto generated Consumer Key & Consumer Secret for an application to other values.

Or is there any way to migrate applications from one environment to another environment, keeping original client id and secret?

Thank you very much in advanced,

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this unless you change values in the database manually.

You need to update `CONSUMER_KEY` and `CONSUMER_SECRET` values in `IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS`, and `CONSUMER_KEY` in `AM_APPLICATION_KEY_MAPPING` table.